# linux locale unset

Tags: linux, locale

I have a ARM based machine with ubuntu distro on it and it often feeds me with this while running various commands:

```
 Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "pl_PL.UTF-8"
```

This is output of the `locale` command

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

What should I do to stop it from popping now and then and configure it properly for the ąęśćźńół [important characters of mine]?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I found it

In some ubuntu distros on non 32bit x86 architectures it is misconfigured.
I needed to

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-pl
```

or
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall language-pack-pl` if already installed
pl is the language code. Change to Yours.

and then

```
cd /usr/lib/locale
sudo ln -s pl_PL.utf8 pl_PL
```

and it's fixed

Comment: Thanks! `apt-get install language-pack-en` worked to help me get en_US.utf8`

Answer (score 2):

Of course installing the needed locales (`sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`) is the best option, if you can.

But I do disable them sometimes, like follows:

```
unset $(locale|cut -d= -f1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

And select locales which You want use.
Next select default and finish.