# gettext() - on 3 languages 2 works one not

Tags: php, gettext

I've got a webpage that contains 3 languages - Polsih, English and German. English and German translations works perfect but Polish doesn't work at all. Where could be the problem? Here is configuration of gettext:

```
    $locale = "pl_PL";
    if (isSet($_GET["lg"])) $locale = $_GET['lg']."_".  strtoupper($_GET['lg']);
    putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale.'.UTF-8');
    bindtextdomain("messages", "./locale");
    bind_textdomain_codeset("messages", 'UTF-8');
    textdomain("messages");
```

Comment: Check `locale -a | grep -i pl` to see if you have `pl_PL.UTF-8`. You may also want to see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527192/linux-locale-unset

Comment: This could be a problem, I don't have access to command line...

Comment: Basic debug: var_dump() your variables and check return values from relevant functions. Don't just trust.

Comment: setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale.'.UTF-8') returns false

Comment: @Maciej - Right, there you are. We still don't know for sure what `$locale` contains but we know for sure that it doesn't contain a valid locale.

Comment: default value of $locale is 'pl_PL', when someone change website language this value could be: 'en_EN' for english version, 'de_DE' for german version and 'pl_PL' for polish version. On different server this works without problems...

Answer (score 0):

Your test code is not particularly helpful. We'll simplify it this way:

```
var_dump( setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pl_PL.UTF-8') );
```

You vaguely suggest in your comments that you're getting `FALSE`. What does it mean? According to [the documentation](http://php.net/setlocale) (I suppose you've already checked it, I'm just posting it here for completeness):

> Returns the new current locale, or `FALSE` if the locale functionality
>   is not implemented on your platform, the specified locale does not
>   exist or the category name is invalid.

So, how do you get a list of available locales? As you've been said:

```
echo `locale -a`;
```